# Function the_posts_pagination() not compatible with WP_Query arguments

Tags: wp-query, categories, loop, pagination

I trying to make a list with posts from specific category. It's supposed to work as the loop in *category.php* file. Unfortunately i have problem with pagination links which are completely not compatible with my WP_Query arguments. No matter what i do, `the_posts_pagination()` function always return links to two pages only.

In tested category i have 12 posts, four of them are sticked posts so final from my query i should get 8 posts because i am using also a `post__not_in` argument with `$stickies = get_option( 'sticky_posts' )` as value. And it happens, the WP_Query returns eight posts. But the big problem starts when it comes to work of `the_posts_pagination()` function.

After set `post_per_page` argument into 2 it should return four pagination links (two posts on each page). Unfortunately the pagination function everytime returns only two links. Page 1 and 2.

Those links works fine only when i set the `post_per_page` argument into number which not causing pagination divided to more than two links. So on `post_per_page` with 4,5,6 or 7 value all is good but even when i set the 8 value, when pagination should have only one link, it returns two links!

Here is my code from *category.php* file:

```
<?php get_header(); 

$category = get_queried_object();   
$stickies = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );   
            
?>

<main>
    <div>
    <?php
    
    $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
    $args = array(
        'post_type'             => 'post',
        'cat'                   => $category->cat_ID, 
        'post__not_in'          => $stickies,
        'posts_per_page'        => 2,
        'paged'                 => $paged
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query($args); 

    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :

        /* Start the Loop */
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
        
            <article>
                <div>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <?php the_title( '<h4><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" itemprop="url" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h4>' ); ?>
                    <div><p><?php echo bs_get_excerpt(22); ?></p></div>
                    <div><?php the_time( 'j F, H:i' );?></div>
                </div>
            </article>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    
            <div class="pagination">

                <?php 
                    
                    $args = array( 
                        'mid_size'                  => 2,
                        'prev_next'                 => false,
                        'screen_reader_text'        => __(' ', 'themename'),
                    );
                    the_posts_pagination($args); 
                    
                ?>

            </div>  <?php 
    
        wp_reset_postdata();
        
    else :
        echo 'no posts from sybmitted query';
    endif;
            
    ?>              
    </div>
</main>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: this problem can be avoided completely and with a big speed boost if you used the `pre_get_posts` filter to modify the category archive query instead of discarding it for a secondary query that has this problem. This will instantly fix all the pagination functions and allow you to remove all the custom query code from `category.php` using a simple filter in `functions.php`. Also note that `post__not_in` and other `not_in` type parameters are _very_ expensive and put a heavy burden on the database because they can involve copying database tables into temporary tables

Comment: Please, look at my code above and tell me why this don't want to work properly. I do not use any special query arguments beside those which are standard in Wordpress. It's a most standard code to simply load a category posts and what should be without any issue, the pagination function doesn't work properly though. This would mean that Wordpress simple does not allow correct pagination on category pages as standard.

Comment: I solved the pagination thing but i have new problem. I tried to set `offset` argument via `pre_get_posts` with `$query->set( 'offset', 5);` and it won't work.

Comment: your code is using a popular anti-pattern that leads to pagination and performance issues. You should not have used a second `WP_Query` in `category.php` to change the parameters, instead you should have used `pre_get_posts`. If you tried that and it didn't work then you will need to update your question to include the code you attempted. Note that you will need to replace your custom query with a standard post loop, not a custom `WP_Query` loop. I'm also not sure why you're trying to use `offset` in `pre_get_posts` when there is no offset parameter in the code you shared